# How to open a Microsoft Access web form without macros executing

Tags: ms-access, vba, office-interop, ms-access-2016

I'm developing a C# application to automatically read meta-data from Microsoft Access forms. Therefore user interference is not possible.

I make use of the [VBA object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192120.aspx) using Office interop.

Some forms have macros that execute when a form is opened. 
To prevent this I open forms in design mode like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Main", acDesign
```

However, if the form has the [IsWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194304.aspx) property set to `true` then I get the following error message:

> Run-Time error '32641': You cannot open the database object 'Main' in design mode with the current settings

I already tried other `AcFormView` modes, but they either don't work or trigger a macro.

- I already do open the Access files using the `shift` key to bypass the `AutoExec` macro.
- I'm using Microsoft Office 2016
- I use VBA to experiment, and C# (.NET 4.5) to develop

Comment: Why not pass an OpenArgs property on the OpenForm.  On the OnOpen event of the form, look for this flag and don't execute any code if it exists.

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to open any Access database without changing the database content itself.